# How Do I Create a max Functor?

Tags: c++, max, bind, functor, c++98

I'm working in C++98 and I want to bind `std::max`. But I need a functor object to use with `std::bind1st`.

I've tried just using `std::pointer_to_binary_function` but the problem seems to be that I can't make a functor out of `std::max`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12350574/2642059

I've also tried `std::ptr_fun` but I get a similar error.

Comment: `std::max` on what types?  In C++98, I don't think `std::bind1st` works on compile time polymorphic function objects, which is the only way to fully wrap all `std::max` overloads into a single function object.

Comment: If this to find the max element in an array? Maybe you can use `std::max_element`

Comment: @Yakk I specifically need it for `int`s, though I'd like to know how to do it in the future for other types. I thought that by doing `std::max<int>` the compiler would create the function and it would behave like a regular function pointer?

Comment: @NeilKirk I primarily wanted to use it in `std::accumulate` and `std::transform`.

Comment: If you have only C++98, trying to use fancy functional programming is just an exercise in getting a migraine, I'm afraid.

Comment: @PiotrS. I have looked at that, but I have trouble justifying it just for this instead of writing my own `std::max` functor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the issue in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12350574/2069064), you can't write a true wrapper functor for max because you can't make any of the types `const T&`. The best you can do is:

```
template <typename T>
struct Max
: std::binary_function<T, T, T>
{
    T operator()(T a, T b) const
    {
        return std::max(a, b);
    }
};

std::bind1st(Max<int>(), 1)(2) // will be 2
```

But that sucks, since you now *have* to copy everything (although if you're just using `int`s, this is totally fine). Best would probably be to just avoid `bind1st` altogether:

```
template <typename T>
struct Max1st
{
    Max1st(const T& v) : first(v) { }

    const T& operator()(const T& second) const {
        return std::max(first, second);
    }

    const T& first;
};
```

Comment: The longer I worked on this the more I had that sinking feeling that this was the only way to accomplish it. I'm going to keep question open another day or so to see if anyone has a better solution then I'll accept this.